# Js Error at Wordpress but not a no wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem with my Js Code. On my Webspace it works  but on a Wordpress systemt it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(accordion){
    $('.item').click(function(accordion){
        if($(this).next('.item-data').css('display') != 'block'){
            $('.active').slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('.item-data').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $('.active').slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

On my private webspace isn't any error but on the webspace with Wordpress:
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

So it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/Gamerfritz/5Wcqk/

Comment: It's `jQuery(function($) { code here });`

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Looks like there are several missing round brackets to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample code you posted, the first two functions are missing opening parentheses '('. You also might want to change the $ signs to say jQuery as this usually works better with wordpress sites (since they can use the $ as a token for something else). You also have function named accordion inside a function named accordion... I don't think it matters because of the way scope is handled, but it doesn't seem like a good idea either way imho.

Maybe try something like this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function accordion (){
jQuery('.item').click (function accordionClick () {
    if(jQuery(this).next('.item-data').css('display') != 'block'){
       jQuery('.active').slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).next('.item-data').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        jQuery('.active').slideUp('slow').removeClass('active');
    }
});
});
```